# Netlify blank page when refresh url with more than one path param using react router

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, netlify

I deployed my react app to netlify but some links looks like it's broken. I'm already aware that I should have a_redirects file or netlify.toml but even if I add

```
[[redirects]]
   from = "/*"
   to = "/index.html"
   status = 200
```

there is still errors on "special url", especially urls with more than one path params like "www.app.org/example/1234656" or "www.app.org/blabla/rerezzer", all url with only one "path param" like *www.app.org/onePara*m working when refreshed.

What I'm missing, I already try to add another redirect rules like from =/*/* but it's not working

Comment: got this error in console SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve the problem, I am experiencing the same difficulties

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue for more than one path param, but tried a simple logic

```
../*  /index.html 200
```

It worked for me

Comment: Does this solve the problem for all routes? Even single param routes? Or must every route contain multiple parameters? And what if I have more than two params?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know this question was asked years ago, but I did just come across the issue too and couldn't find a solution
Hopefully, someone would need it
The solution provided here didn't work for me
What I had to do was to include `<base href="/" />` in my head section in my index.html file

```
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
```